# php - trouble getting /r/n to be a <br> in email message

Tags: php, email, newline

I have a web form that allows a person to enter text and then send an email using swift mail.   The text they enter may contain \r\n.  I send email from swift mail in text/html.  Prior to sending the email, I have attempted to do a sting replace on the \r\n, as well as a nl2br function on the user entered text so that all occurrences of \r\n are changed to 
; yet in all cases the email still arrives with \r\n being displayed in the text message, as opposed to actual line breaks.

**below is the code snippet to prep the text and the email code.**

```
/* replace all cr/lf with a <br> */
$ind_msg = nl2br($ind_msg);

/* send the email message */
$status = send_email($db, $ind_email, $ind_name, $sender, $sender_name, $msg_subj, $ind_msg, "");
```

**email code**

```
/* create the message */
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo(array($recipient => $recipient_name));
$message->setSubject($msg_subject);
$message->setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
$message->setBody($msg_body);
$message->setFrom(array($sender => $sender_name));
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: You're wrong about `nl2br()`. It doesn't replace new lines. It adds html line breaks after them.

Comment: Can you post the possible input along with expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$ind_msg = str_replace(array('\r\n'), array('<br>'), $ind_msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

nl2br do not replace newline-chars. It adds the "br" tag before all newline chars. If you want to replace them, use str_replace();

vg
bytecounter